# installing ubuntu on a voyo v3 mini pc

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, support

I had some trouble installing ubuntu on my mini laptop (asus x205ta) and found that there is no good, smooth and straight forward way to install ubuntu on it instead of the factory win 10. so now i feel that checking before i am buying is probably a good idea.

Will i be able to install a regular ubuntu \ Lubuntu on [this](http://www.geekbuying.com/item/VOYO-V3-Intel-Cherry-Trail-X7-Z8700-4K-Mini-PC-Windows10-64Bit-4G-128G-2-4G-5G-Dual-Band-WiFi-Gigabit-LAN-Type-C-Bluetooth-4-0-362092.html?source=ShareAsale) mini pc?

How can i check that?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it should work but... Cherry Tail  has its quirks. It's much better than Bay Trail though. You just need to install in UEFI mode with Secure Boot disabled. Other than that it's the same like any other desktop or notebook. If you have a specific issue I suggest you open a new question with details of the problem.

Comment: @CelticWarrior thanks, what do you mean by its quirks?

Comment: I mean it may freeze occasionally but the performance has been increased substantially with newer kernels. Choose the latest release 17.04 for better performance. 16.10 also good, I've tested it intensively in a Celeron Cherry Trail and it worked better than expected for such entry level hardware.

Comment: will it load a 64 bit os in the bios without any added files to the iso?

Comment: No problem. h was an issue with Bay Trails, not with yours.

Comment: great, thanks! so, for now is it advisable to take this model or it is better to choose something like Intel core based machine that will operate more smoothly?  are the quirks noticeable? is everything else fine? display, sound etc?

Comment: As I mentioned before, as far as I could test, all is working as expected with current releases bt then it was with a slightly different CPU of the same family.